# Rings as a monetary system

Tags: society, economy

Can rings be used as a monetary system? Are there any flaws? I took inspiration from Celtic ring money, rings made from different metals- the value of a ring depended on the material it was made out of. E.G. A copper ring would cost less than a silver ring, and that would cost less than a golden ring etc.

People would wear these on fingers. I think there might be problems with thievery etc. Any ideas on how to make it better or express any flaws?

Comment: Sonic the Hedgehog. Boom.

Comment: @user45266 The rings were just a means to an end. The real end was the Chaos emeralds.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The emeralds are just a status symbol being purchased with the rings you worked for.

Comment: The norse would make chains out of precious metals, you could just hack/bend off a link of chain to pay for something. so that would be a series of interlocked rings, still valued by weight though.

Comment: What about the [Rai stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rai_stones)? 4 metre, 4 tonne rings might be a little cumbersome to wear, but maybe your people aren't human?

Comment: Dependant on your technology levels, if we're talking medieval, people didn't have daily costs like phone bills, rates, etc, just rent & food. If you were paid in 5 rings by your boss each week, gave 2-3 to your landlord and 1-2 to the merchant for food you bought that week, you were done, Barter would still be a legit transaction, so you don't need a lot of coins on your hands.

Today, I have a ring on my finger that contains a USD drive with bitcoin addresses & RDF chip? for bank transfers.. I might have certain rings for certain banks/citcoins. so also plausible for future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Traditionally Japanese coins had holes through the middle and could be strung together for ease of transportation:

Japanese coins courtesy of Wikipedia https://i.stack.imgur.com/06CoU.jpg

In the Dune series the Fremen would use rings as currency backed by water, these weren't worn on fingers but in their hair so another take on stringing them.

So it's not an uncommon idea, however it's probably not a good idea to wear them on fingers as people have different finger sizes so often the rings wouldn't fit and you have a maximum finger capacity for rings, it would also be difficult to hold things if your fingers are covered in rings. Imagine bandits attack you and your fingers are unable to bend due to being covered in rings so you can't grab your sword. I imagine in such a world people would end up stringing the rings together anyway.

Comment: hm... i didnt think about that... thanks for the insight! yeah now that i think about it... ill have to either work out a new monetary system or try to figure out an original idea to 'store' the rings. Thanks!

Comment: There was a pretty good book where in one area rings were given as status, the more valuable the ring the more they respected you.  You would keep them in a bowl in the entryway so that people could examine them while they waited for you--hmm--Ahh I think it was from "The Kingkiller Chronicles". not the same but an interesting idea.

Comment: Another problem with rings is that they're hard to divide. With coins, people needing to make change sometimes actually physically cut them up. (A pirate's "pieces of eight" are Spanish *reales* cut into eight *bits* apiece.) Rings don't have that option, and tend to be large enough that they would represent a fair amount of wealth.

Comment: Denmark still has holes in their 1 Krone coins even today.

Comment: @vsz - That's a relatively new design, though. Until 1989 (Queen Margarethe II), the 1 kr did not have a hole.

Answer (score 8):

Anything can be used as money, as long as the society using it agrees that it has value, or represents value, in a consistent manner. For some examples, see https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WeirdCurrency - specifically, the last section, with "Real World" examples.

Chinese coins at one time were square-pierced disks; this is the origin of the square-pierced tokens in modern mah-jongg sets, and also ultimately led to the symbols on the "dot" and "bamboo" suits in the game; the dot was originally a single coin, and the "bamboo" stick was actually a string of 100 coins.

Answer (score 4):

Not an easy system.

Coins can be minted with basic technology. Rings can be easily made too, but putting any distinguishing marks on a ring is technologically more difficult ([Signet rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(emblem)#Signet_rings)). You can have plain rings, but then anyone can make rings, and they would no longer have a face value.

Engraving would work for high value rings, the ones that worth more than their weight in gold.

P.S. This answer assumes that the ring must be wearable and not just a "topological ring" like pierced coin.

Comment: But "face value" is a rather abstract concept, and really doesn't work if the populace is used to currency that's actual precious metals.  They'll develop various ways of telling older, more pure coinage from the adulterated ones the new Emperor just introduced.

Comment: yes, i meant it as a wearable ring... now that ive read some thoughts on it, i really need to think the whole monetary system through again... Thankyou for the answer!

Comment: @jamesqf having a limited set of instruments with face value is infinitely better than having no face value at all. Without face value, one would have to always use scales and have suspicion about composition of a ring.

Comment: @Alexander: Coins with intrinsic value did not have "face values" (that is, inscriptions saying *so many units*) until very very recently. Greek coins, Roman coins, medieval coins, Renaissance coins did not carry such inscriptions. Everybody was supposed to know the sizes, weights and engravings of coins in common circulation.

Comment: @AlexP so, the face value of old coins was "1". My point is that without a legible stamp, it is very difficult to determine intrinsic value of an object.

Comment: @Alexander: Ah now I get it. You don't mean a face value as such, but a stamp of authenticity.

Comment: @Alexander: I see we're using different meanings for "face value".  I meant that the coin was supposed to have a value much different than its actual metal weight, as when the US replaced its silver coins with base metal ones - and the silver ones quickly disappeared from circulation.

Answer (score 2):

Besides real-life cultures, the videogame Tyranny uses rings as currency:

https://tyranny.gamepedia.com/Rings

These rings aren't really coins, but more like loops of metal. They also aren't worn on fingers, but on strings, ropes, or leather cords tied around the waist or neck. In fact, as stated in the linked wiki article:

"As rings are used as currency, it is considered vulgar to wear rings as adornment or jewelry. Such decorations are seen as vulgar, and those who wear them are held in contempt."

Of course, you're free to invent whatever customs you like.

Threading rings with cords or tying them with ropes makes for easier transport (and would allow individuals to carry more than 18 rings (assuming 2 per finger and 1 per thumb) at a time.

If what you're looking for is more like coins with holes, you might still tie them together with cord or string, for ease of use. Specific stacks of rings might be a standard lump sum. For example, a string holding 10 copper rings might be the in-universe equivalent of a €5,- bill.

That might lead to slang terms for specific amounts of money. Think of people referring to 1 dollar as a 'buck' in reference to deers, which were hunted so much that a deer hide at one point only cost 1 dollar. Hence, a buck. Or I've heard people refer to 100 dollar bills as Franklins, in reference to the guy depicted on the bill.

Of course, you can always carry rings in a purse or bag instead. That might be less vulnerable to theft, depending on the construction of the bag and cords under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Not a new concept. Coins have been struck with holes in the middle to reduce their value
https://c8.alamy.com/comp/EJX2RP/a-string-of-ancient-coins-EJX2RP.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e3/77/dd/e377dde3f7fa5d76f54b4ce11395dc1e--chinese-style-feng-shui.jpg
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmbZjeAM58oWw3aP-edjUU1RM-UNf2fd3H_TpXC66N8kIt-CBJAw
Wearing them as rings is a problem as it both limits mobility and the amount of money you can carry

Comment: Please note that the result of Google searches is highly dependent on your previous search history, as well as that it obviously can change over time (Google is likely to revise their algorithms, and online content changes with time). If it matters, then please reference the relevant content directly, and/or incorporate the salient points directly into your answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Done

Comment: You can use markdown to format your links. Use an open bracket followed by the text you want, and then use a close bracket. Without a space, put the link in parenthesis. All together, it looks like this: [ ]( ). Here is an example: [The smartest user on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/current).

Answer (score 1):

Well people have made money out of rocks he or she with the largest rock or boulder was the richest one in town sooooo you could do it by ring color, weight, or start adding in gemstones or rocks set into the rings. Rings could be carried not on the finger but around the neck for high shoppers. For low shoppers hands, wrists, or up on the bicep. The old fashion pouch would also work if you are allowed to employ pins for which to string the rings upon. Rings could be so tiny not even a baby could wear it or so large they become collars that fit over the entire skull.

Looping them on guard dog's necks who are trained to never leave their owner is one way having a tiered sorting box is another small enough (depending on the status and wealth of the owner) would slip in and out the ring sizes arranged by the person so they have what they need.

Yes theft would be a possibility like any society so securing it on ones self or at home is also priority would they hide the rigs in false drawers say under the mantle shelf? Or inside a sock tucked into their shoe? Thieves would have to look longer and in more places to find the tiny loot but big large hoops no problem but that is a problem porting it about what if you get the grand daddy of all rings that is bigger then the door? Made just so the owner could say how rich they were?

Fools metal work could be common too left out for thieves to steal. Maybe a test is required before any transaction is complete to secure the metal used. A device, magic, harmonics,biting could all work but what about the morron with a million rings who comes in and crashes the economy? Or only the king/queen may have the largest hoops in the kingdom cuz they say so or will kill you.

Remember the society I told you about with rocks ROCKS? Yeah those things were everywhere when too many people got too many boulders they eventually switched the currency to....seashells... yeah...so rings can be fine or coins with holes in them too just if its a common item and isolation is why they do it until something else comes along to replace it just think of the issues with normal coins.

Answer (score 0):

Chains

You could make chains out of precious metals. You could just break or if gold bend open a link of the chains at different places to fraction out money, the chains could be worn as belts to help make them secure or even many chains off a belt making a kind of chain skirt. Of course this relies on precious metals valued by weight instead of any standardized currency. Standardizing rings is tricky (proving they are standardized is even harder) and you will occasionally generate some broken rings.

Comment: Or you could simply run a string or chain through the middle of the rings, makes it far easier to take off the rings, simply untie the string or unhook the chain. An alternative, closer to your idea, would be to have keychains, a string of metal coiled up into a ring shape. You can pull the piece of metal open and slide other things on it, do it enough and you’ve created a chain. Its similar to the idea of creating paperclip chains. Or you could have rings linked by butted links. These are rings of iron or steel which have a split in them, you can easily bend these to open or close the loop.